# SageMath/Python: Using scientific notation results in an equation being evaluated incorrectly

Tags: python, sage

I'm writing a program that checks if graphs are Ricci-flat. This involves calculating the Ricci curvature of each edge in the graph; if it's zero for all edges, the graph is Ricci-flat, and it isn't otherwise.

Sometimes, due to numerical error, the program will calculate the Ricci curvature of an edge to be a very small number ~10^-16 when it's actually zero; therefore, the program actually checks whether the absolute value of the Ricci curvature is less than 10^-10 for each edge. Here's the shortened version of how it works (the full code is below):

```
#Takes as input a graph G, outputs True if G is Ricci-flat or False if it isn't
def ricci_flat(G):

    for i in G.edges(): #iterate over each edge in the graph
        curvature = [calculate the Ricci curvature of edge i]
        #If the edge has nonzero Ricci curvature, the graph is not Ricci-flat
        if abs(curvature) >= 10**(-10): return(False)

    #If it runs through everything and never finds a Ricci-flat edge
    return(True)
```

However, the output of the function seems to depend upon how I represent 10^-10 just before the `return(False)` statement. Specifically, if I use `10**(-10)` (like above) or `10^(-10)`, the function **always** returns `False` on the first edge, even if its Ricci curvature is zero (according to a `print(curvature)` line before the return statement). But if I use `0.0000000001` or `1/(10**10)`, the function behaves as normal, returning `False` if and only if the Ricci curvature of an edge is greater than 10^-10. I'm able to use (say) the decimal representation to get the job done, but I'm curious as to why this happens.

Here's the full function:

```
import numpy as np
from sage.all import *

def ricci_flat(G):   #Calculates the ricci-curvature of the graph G edge by edge
    #Returns True if a graph is OLLY-Ricci-flat and False otherwise

    #Extract graph information
    Adjacency=G.adjacency_matrix()
    Vertices=G.vertices()
    Degrees=G.degree()
    Edges=G.edges()
    Neighbors=[G.neighbors(i) for i in Vertices]
    n=len(Vertices)

    ############################################
    #Define distance and neighbors functions
    def d(x, y):
        return G.distance(x, y)

    #Define alpha function -> hardcode this function straight into mu?
    def alpha(a, b):
        return 1/(max(Degrees[a], Degrees[b])+1) #...why this value?

    #Define probability distribution function
    def mu(a,b,z):
        if z==a: return alpha(a,b)
        elif z in Neighbors[a]: return (1-alpha(a,b))/Degrees[a]
        else: return 0

    ############################################
    #Compute OLLY Ricci-flatness
    for i,j,_ in Edges:
        #Set-up optimisation method
        p = MixedIntegerLinearProgram(maximization=False)
        A = p.new_variable(real=True) # A[x, y] is the transformation function
        p.set_objective(sum(A[x, y]*d(x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)))
        #Add constraints
        for x in range(n):
            p.add_constraint(sum(A[x, y] for y in range(n))==mu(i,j,x)) #...sum of row
            p.add_constraint(sum(A[y, x] for y in range(n))==mu(j,i,x)) #...sum of column
            for y in range(n): p.add_constraint(0<=A[x, y]) #...all variables non-negative
        # OLLY curvature for edge
        curvature = 1-p.solve()

        #print(abs(curvature))
        #For debugging: sometimes returns 0, sometimes returns something less than 10^-15

        #If the edge is non-Ricci-flat, end the function with False
        #Doesn't work correctly unless 10**(-10) is replaced with 1/(10**10)
        if abs(curvature) >= 10**(-10): return(False)

    #If it runs through everything and it never finds a non-Ricci-flat edge:
    return(True)
```

And here's an example construction of a graph that *should* be Ricci-flat. If the above code has `1/(10**10)` or `0.0000000001` before the `return(False)` statement, `ricci_flat(A1A1)` correctly returns `True`. But if it has `10**(-10)` or `10^(-10)` instead, it incorrectly returns `False`.

```
import numpy as np
from sage.all import *
n = 6
v = n**2
adj = np.zeros((v,v)) #Adjacency matrix of the graph
for i in range(v):
    if i<v-n:
        adj[i,i+n]=1
        adj[i+n,i]=1
    if i<n:
        adj[i,i+v-n]=1
        adj[i+v-n,i]=1
    if i%n!=0:
        adj[i,i-1]=1
        adj[i-1,i]=1
    else:
        adj[i,i+n-1]=1
        adj[i+n-1,i]=1

mat = matrix(adj).change_ring(ZZ)
#A1A1 is a Ricci-flat graph
A1A1 = Graph(mat)
```

(The error persists even if I use different Ricci-flat graphs, this is just an example for testing purposes. Typing `10**(-10) == 1/(10**10)` into the Sage shell returns `True`, as expected.)

Comment: Using `10^(-10)` won't work because this is Python code, so `^` is Python's bytewise xor operator, not exponentiation. In the Sage shell, `^` is preparsed and converted to exponentiation. I don't know why `10**(-10)` isn't working.

Comment: Actually, `10**(-10)` does work for me. What version of Sage are you using? What OS, how did you install, etc.?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I'm using SageMath version 9.2, Python 3.8.5. MacOS version 10.14.6. Binary distribution, "Unix-style command line" option (as opposed to the native Mac application).

Comment: Can you try upgrading? Version 9.2 is from last November, and version 9.4 was just released. It is possible that a bug was fixed in the meantime.